# How correctly open window inside a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, gtk#

I tried to open window from thread, but open window was frozen.
Code in the first window(inside a thread):

```
MyProject.MainModuleWindow mmw = new MyProject.MainModuleWindow();
mmw.Show();
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Best_Practices GTK is not thread safe, so all calls to UI should be done in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the thread's `ApartmentState` to `ApartmentState.STA`.

```
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OpenAWindow));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

The [default ApartmentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a newly creating thread is MTA.

```
New threads are initialized as ApartmentState.MTA if their apartment state  
has not been set before they are started.
```

You need to set it to `ApartmentState.STA` manually when you manipulate with window or dialog.

The underlying reason why you need to set thread's ApartmentState is your window may [interop with COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Because COM classes use apartments, the common language runtime needs to 
create and initialize an apartment when calling a COM object in a COM 
interop situation.
```

This is true in Windows and .NET environment, I have no idea if this fits in your situation. Try it out.

Comment: I already tried to set ApartmentState.STA